# Any alternative to msConvertURL() in Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

IE has this helpful method [msConvertURL()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn254951(v=vs.85).aspx) on [DragEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974339(v=vs.85).aspx), that makes it possible to convert otherwise inaccessible files to blob or data URIs.

I wonder if there's any alternative in Chrome and Firefox?